# Two-dimensional algebras over complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

I have read that there are two 2-dimensional algebras over the complex numbers, but I wanted to see what they are and how they are formed. I understand how to show that there are three 2-dimensional algebras over the reals and am trying to alter that but I don't know if what I'm doing is right!
I'm quite new to this area of Maths so haven't covered Lie algebras or anything advanced.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you show what you've done so far.

Comment: Giving a summary of the real case would IMHO enhance the usefulness of the question to future readers. It would also serve as a response to @Travis . And... Welcome to Math.SE. Our site culture has evolved in such a way that we more often than not appreciate a bit more context in questions. Such as what has been suggested to you in the comments.

Comment: To be sure, by "algebra" do you mean "unital associative algebra"?

Comment: The $2$-dimensional algebra $A=\langle e_1,e_2\rangle$ with products $e_1\cdot e_2=e_2\cdot e_1=-e_1$ is commutative, but not associative, because $e_1\cdot (e_2\cdot e_2)=0$, but $(e_1\cdot e_2)\cdot e_2=e_1$. Would you consider such algebras ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commutative algebras have been classified up to dimension $n\le 6$ over any algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic, see the article of Björn Poonen "[Isomorphism types of commutative algebras of finite rank over an algebraically closed field](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/dimension6.pdf)". This includes the unital associative commutative algebras.
Complex associative algebras (not necessarily commutative) have been classified up to dimension $4$, see for example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0932). In dimension $2$, there are four different complex associative algebras, see the table in section $2.1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal{u}$ be the unity of A. I construct a base { $\mathcal{u}, \mathcal{v}$} of A over $\mathbb{C}$ . Then $\mathcal{v}\cdot\mathcal{v}=a\cdot \mathcal{u}+b\cdot\mathcal{v}$. If  $a+\frac{b^{2}}{4}=0$ it is easy to find $\mathcal{w}\in A$ such that $w\cdot w=0$ and $w\notin \mathbb{C}u$($w$ has the form $\alpha\cdot u+\beta\cdot v, \beta\neq 0$). In this way I obtain a new base {$u, w$}. Now, I consider the correspondence $u\rightarrow \hat{1}$, $w\rightarrow \hat{x}$. Therefore, A is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{C}[X]}{(X^2)}$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. If $a+\frac{b^{2}}{4}\neq 0$ it is easy to find $\mathcal{w}\in A$ such that $w\cdot w=-1$ and $w\notin \mathbb{C}u$. In this way I obtain a new base {$u, w$}. Now, I consider the correspondence $u\rightarrow (1,0)$, $w\rightarrow (0,1)$. Therefore, A is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} $x$\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.